# Android: how to draw different background for Button when selected?

Tags: android

I would like my Button to draw with a transparent background by default, to draw with a dark blue background when pressed, and to draw with a light blue background when selected.  I set the Button's background to the below selector, and am calling `Button.setSelected(!Button.isSelected())` when the button is clicked.  The pressed state works properly, but the Button draws with a transparent background when selected.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tranpsshape" /> 
  <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tranpsshape" /> 
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/pressedbuttonshape" /> 
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/selectedshape" /> 
  <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tranpsshape" /> 
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tranpsshape" /> 
  <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/selectedshape" /> 
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/tranpsshape" /> 
</selector>
```

selectedshape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#A3DAF2"/>
</shape>
```

pressedbuttonshape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#4ABDE8/>
</shape>
```

tranpsshape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#00000000"/>

</shape>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accordind to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html)

> During each state change, the state list is traversed top to bottom and the first item that matches the current state will be used—the selection is not based on the "best match," but simply the first item that meets the minimum criteria of the state.

So you need to place `state_selected` above `state_focused`. So your file will look like this

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tranpsshape" /> 
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tranpsshape" /> 
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/pressedbuttonshape" /> 
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/selectedshape" />         
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/selectedshape" /> 
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tranpsshape" /> 
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tranpsshape" /> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tranpsshape" /> 
</selector>
```

Comment: both answers are perfect, selected this one for being first (barely).  thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> The selection is not based on the "best match," but simply the first
>   item that meets the minimum criteria of the state.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

So I think it's transparent because one of those states is matching the current state

```
  <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tranpsshape" /> 
  <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tranpsshape" />
  <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tranpsshape" /> 
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tranpsshape" />
```

Try to put

```
<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/selectedshape" />
```

at the top or add criterias to the previous cases.